# F5 to run Visual Studio Test in debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-test-runner

I'm using Visual Studio Test for C++, and am debugging a specific test. Microsoft has provided all kinds of ways to run the test in the debugger, but none that I really like. I am getting tired of having to go find the test code and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or mousing around which I hate). I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> behavior from any source code context.

Is there a way to hook <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the selected test(s) in the debugger?

I've tried setting my test project as startup, but that makes <kbd>F5</kbd> "unable to start" because the test is a DLL.

Comment: I would really like this behavior as well.

Answer (score 7):

Locate your `vstest.console.exe` to run the test DLL via <kbd>F5</kbd>.

In my Visual Studio 2017 Community edition that would be putting the following path into `Start external program` under Debug settings:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe
```

And as `Command line arguments` just put the DLLs file name. Now you can use <kbd>F5</kbd> to start debugging a test when `Set as StartUp Project`.

Comment: It works and answers the question, but personally I think it's a better experience to add a different key-binding to the menu "Test>Debug>All Tests".

Comment: To save someone some time to look it up: /Tests:MytestFunc in the command line arguments after the dll-name runs a specific test...

Answer (score 0):

I found how to set this using resharper:
https://superuser.com/questions/724380/repeat-last-test-in-debug-mode-in-visual-studio-2013
**BUT** now F5 will not perform Continue in Debug. it seems visual studio don't separate Run and Continue commands.  (I am using visual studio 2013)
so I set Alt+F5 instead.